# Invoke shp2pgsql using system2() in R

Tags: r, bash, postgresql, postgis

I want to write an R script that will automatically send ESRI shapefiles into PostgreSQL using the `shp2pgsql` option in Bash.

```
# in Bash
shp2pgsql -I -s Port Shapefile schema.table | psql DB

# in R
Command<-c("-I","-s",Port,"shapefile","schema.table","|","psql","DB")
system2("shp2pgsql",Command,wait=FALSE)
/bin/sh: shp2pgsql: command not found
/bin/sh: psql: command not found

# Alternative in R using system
system("shp2pgsql -I -s 4326 shapefile schema.table | psql DB")
/bin/sh: shp2pgsql: command not found
/bin/sh: psql: command not found
```

*I understand there are other ways to achieve this result, and would appreciate answers in that regard. However, I am particularly interested in why the system2 method does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to change to the path *within R*

```
# Find the correct directory
# Importantly, you do not want "locate psql".
# You want the directory psql is in, i.e., bin, not the full path to psql
Directory<-system("locate bin | grep /Applications/Postgres.app",inter=TRUE)[[1]]

# Create a command to redirect the path
Export<-paste("export PATH=",Directory,":$PATH",sep="")

# Create a command listing your shp2psql command
Command<-"shp2pgsql -I -s 4326 shapefile schema.table | psql DB"

# Join them using && to ensure that Export finishes before executing command
FinalCommand<-paste(Export,"&&",Command,sep=" ")

# Export it to your system
system(FinalCommand)
```